# Where can I find a collection of samples of Mandarin spoken words, annotated with pinyin and tones?

Tags: tones, learning, spoken, listening, database

I recently built the following app that lets you listen to a Chinese word and asks tests your tone hearing ability:

https://tones.strokes.ovh/

I'd like to extend it, but in order to get there I need a collection of Chinese sound samples, annotated with pinyin and tones - and ideally, also Chinese characters related to the sample.

Where could I find such a collection?

Comment: What about a dictionary?

Comment: Your app ( in my mind ) has a few problems. One of them is that it's not clear whether you want the tone as it was spoken or the tone as it belongs to the character. A word like 语法 (yu3fa3) is a prime example: Your clip says (yu2fa3) because when multiple 3rd tones will turn earlier ones into 2nd tones. But without knowing the tones for 语(3) and 法(3), there would be no way to know whether it was 23 or 33.

Related to that is, of course, the neutral tones. Some of your clips use the neutral tones but you (I guess) wanted the "true tones"...

Comment: For example: https://tones.strokes.ovh/sample/tou2_fa4.ogg and https://tones.strokes.ovh/sample/ying3_xiang3.ogg

Comment: And I just realized this was a month ago.... but there's my feedback if you still want it :P

Answer (score 2):

Some websites or apps you may need:
[image]
https://www.chineasy.com/ All you need. Looks like the best one.

[image]
https://www.chinesecharacterart.com/ No audio is a shortcoming

[image]
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hanzi-oracle/id736544977?mt=8
IOS app, not test.
Hope it's helpful